# Is there a word for using basic phonetics to teach someone your name's correct pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, names

For instance, if my name was Rehana then I'd tell them my name is pronounced like ray as in a ray of sunshine, hana as in Hannah. Is there an easier way to explain how I'm simplifying my name for others?

Comment: Um... phonetic spelling is when you spell a word how you say it: *police* -> *puh-LEES* etc.

Comment: It would be useful to have a word for that but I don't think there is one. You could say, "I tell them syllable by syllable how it's pronounced," or "I give them an example of (the pronunciation of) each syllable," or "I tell them the sound of each syllable". But those are all a bit wordy and less precise than your original method, which is also more fun to hear. If they know The Sound Of Music" you could try saying, "I have to 'doe a deer' my name."

Answer (score 0):

This may sound like the wrong answer but in regular conversation, most people just correct it with the word 'it's.'
For example, when somebody pronounces my last name Lee or Lay I correct them "it's Leigh, L-e-i-g-h"

Comment: Are you saying your name *Leigh* is not pronounced the same as *Lee* or *Lay*? Everyone I've ever met with *Leigh* as a first or last name pronounces it *Lee*. The OP's example works in writing - how would you explain your name's pronunciation in writing?

Comment: You're saying that spelling a non-phonetic name helps pronounce it?

Comment: I miss spoke, its pronounces lee. But people call me leg,, lay, And phone solicitors like to call me Lehigh LOL. But yeah, spell it out.